# Receiving warning "implicit declaration of function 'strlen'"

Tags: c, posix

I have a some simple code, but I am receiving a warning:

```
-bash-3.2$ gcc -Wall print_process_environ.c -o p_p
print_process_environ.c: In function 'print_process_environ':
print_process_environ.c:24: warning: implicit declaration of function 'strlen'
print_process_environ.c:24: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'strlen'
```

The following is the code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <strings.h>

    void
    print_process_environ(pid_t pid)
    {
        int     fd;
        char    filename[24];
        char    environ[1024];
        size_t  length;
        char    *next_var;

        snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "/proc/%d/environ", (int)pid);
        printf("length of filename: %d\n", strlen(filename));

        fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
......
```

The definition of `strlen()` is:

```
   #include <string.h>

   size_t strlen(const char *s);
```

how to get rid of this warning.

Comment: Including `strings.h` twice is not the same as including `string.h` once...

Answer (score 53, accepted):

it's `#include <string.h>` . You are spelling it wrong in your code. Also if you ever get that warning in your compiler .. always do `man function_name` on terminal to see the header required for that function

```
 #include <string.h> // correct header
 #include <strings.h> // incorrect header - change this in your code to string.h
```

Comment: Didn't know about the `man function_name`, really good to know!

Answer (score 9):

You were bitten by a easy to make mistake, you included the [posix strings.h](http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/7posix/strings.h/) header:

```
#include <strings.h>
```

instead of:

```
#include <string.h>
```

the *posix* header includes support for:

```
int    bcmp(const void *, const void *, size_t); (LEGACY )
void   bcopy(const void *, void *, size_t); (LEGACY )
void   bzero(void *, size_t); (LEGACY )
int    ffs(int);
char  *index(const char *, int); (LEGACY )
char  *rindex(const char *, int); (LEGACY )
int    strcasecmp(const char *, const char *);
int    strncasecmp(const char *, const char *, size_t);
```

which are all non-standard functions, this also explains the lack of error, I am having a hard time finding a good reference but *BSD* systems version of *strings.h* used to also include *string.h*.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the code was `#include <stdlib.h>` and my output was :

[image]

Solution:

Changed `stdlib.h` to `stdio.h` and the warning was gone

In short, the compiler is trying to tell you that it couldn't find the declaration of a function. This is a result of a). No header file included b) wrong header file name .eg" sring.h"